# How to make relationship two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to learn relationship between tables, I have two tables APPLICATION,SERVER_STATUS.The following is the table structure for the  application.

```
mysql> desc application;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| applicationId     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| applicationName   | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| startDate         | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| endDate           | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| prjectedStartTime | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| prjectedEndTime   | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| currentAction     | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| danoneValidation  | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| comments          | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now each application has 3 server statuses like in-progress,ready and completed.For maintaining the server I have taken a table SERVER_STATUS,there I am maintaining server statuses like in-progress,ready and completed. How do I make relationship between these 2 tables?
    The following is my tables structure.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

check This.

```
select * from application a 
inner join serverstatus s on s.status=a.status and s.applicationId=a.applicationId
```

You can make relationship among this table using common column.
which is status and applicationId.